# ¿Como pasar una base de datos sql de mi localhost a un hosting?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hosting, conexión

He pasado mi pagina de mi localhost a byethost(un host gratuito) pero al intertar pasar la base de datos a mi cpanel me aparece esto en mi php que basededatos.php

**Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /home/vol10_4/byethost8.com/b8_33777243/htdocs/Pagina Compramas/php/basededatos.php on line 9**

**Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given in /home/vol10_4/byethost8.com/b8_33777243/htdocs/Pagina Compramas/php/basededatos.php on line 10**

Esta es mi basededatos.php, una conexion cambie el localhost y el root pero no se porque me aparece ese error

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect("185.27.134","b8_33777243","XXXXXX","abarrotes");
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8")
?>
```

Mi base de datos lo pase al phpmyadmin de byethost

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el usuario que puse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero que nada, hay que revisar lo que uno ha escrito... según tu navegador veo que accedes a través de una IP a la web... según tu código php, veo que esa IP no está bien escrita: `mysqli_connect("185.27.134"`... verás, las IP suelen tener CUATRO bloques de números, no tres.

Comment: Ya puse el ip completo, pero me sale "Connection refused" en vez de "Connection timed out "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por las sugerencias, al final debia poner esto en el nombre del localhost
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recuerda verificar una de las respuestas que te sirvieron.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 2 errores fáciles de detectar, como ya te dijeron, siempre debes revisar lo que escribes.

Te falta el ultimo bloque de la IP y te falta el punto y coma de la línea donde defines el charset.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("185.27.134.10","b8_33777243","XXXXXX","abarrotes");
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
?>
```

Por ultimo, si ese es un mismo archivo, no necesitas abrir y cerrar PHP a cada bloque de código, en uno solo es la mejor practica.

---

No olvides marcar la respuesta como **Aceptada** si resuelve tu problema/duda. :-)

Comment: si, ya lo habia puesto completo antes, ahora me sale esto:                                                                                                                    
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/vol10_4/byethost8.com/b8_33777243/htdocs/Pagina Compramas/php/basededatos.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given in /home/vol10_4/byethost8.com/b8_33777243/htdocs/Pagina Compramas/php/basededatos.php on line 7

Comment: @JoseGodoyCebreros Observa que **ahora** la base de datos no se llama `abarrotes` sino **`b8_33777243_abarrotes`** supongo que el hosting gratuito añade el valor `b8_33777243_` de forma aleatoria y quizá no puedas cambiar eso, entonces, tienes que actualizar el código de conexión a: **`$conexion = mysqli_connect("185.27.134.10","b8_33777243","XXXXXX","b8_33777243_abarrotes");`**

Comment: Gracias, no me habia percatado de eso, tambien vi que el nombre del localhost era " sql101.byethost8.com" por eso tambien no me funcionaba

Answer (score 1):

Si estás mudando todo el proyecto al hosting (código + base de datos), entonces no cambia nada, el server seguirá siendo `localhost`, ya que el servicio SQL sigue estando en el mismo lugar.

Por defecto, y por seguridad, MySQL no va a permitir las conexiones externas abiertamente. Si tuvieses el caso de que la base de datos está en un servidor y el desarrollo en otro servidor, entonces en MySQL tendrás que [crear un usuario con hostname](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html) del servidor de desarrollo.

En el caso de Cpanel, al menos en la versión que tengo, hay un apartado llamado "Remote MySQL", donde se puede crear el domino (Host / IP / Wildcard) del servidor que tendrá acceso. Pero, como dije, si estás mudando todo, no hay que cambiar nada.